# Posso usar webflux para meu client receber notificações em tempo real?

Tags: spring-boot

Tenho dois sistemas, 1 legado e o sistema novo. O sistema novo precisará ser atualizado em tempo real, a cada momento que o legado for atualizado. Com isso pensei que o webflux iria me ajudar, entao criei uma POC com mongo e tal,

```
@RestController
public class ConversionTableProductTypeResource {

    @Autowired
    private ConversionTableProductTypeService service;

    @GetMapping()
    public Flux<ConversionTableProductType> getAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/stream",  produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<ConversionTableProductType> getAllStream() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public Mono<ConversionTableProductType> createTweets(@Valid @RequestBody ConversionTableProductType tweet) {
        return service.save(tweet);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> deleteTweet(@PathVariable(value = "id") String tweetId) {

        return service.findById(tweetId)
                .flatMap(existingTweet ->
                        service.delete(existingTweet)
                                .then(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK)))
                )
                .defaultIfEmpty(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }

}
```

E então achei q isso era a solução para meu problemas, pois pensei, o legado poderia atualizar o mongo e minha tela iria magicamente se atualizar.

Pode ser que meus testes nao estivessem corretos, pois fiz a chamada do /stream pelo browser ou pelo postman.

Poderiam dar uma luz, se estou pensando do jeito certo, e se sim, o que fiz de errado?